# Cannot create new Android Projects in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, project

Using 3.6.2. When I choose to create a new Android Project, I enter a name, 'FirstProject' but the Finish button remains hollow and I cannot get past creating the project.

I did a little Google research and found a common cause of this is that the support folder that exists in the SDK's extras folder needs to be duplicated and the duplicate named to compatibility. I've done this now, and restarted Eclipse, but this still hasn't fixed the issue.

I also read that Juno causes this problem, but I'm not using Juno.

Has anyone experienced this problem before? Very eager to start an Android App!!

EDIT: A screen of the error:

[image]

Comment: No, I have not experienced this issue before. Ever. Can you attach a screenshot of the dialog you see when you create a new project? Did you download at least one Android SDK? Did you update the eclipse preferences for Android with the directory containing your Android SDKs?

Comment: Why you do not have any build SDK chosen? Do you have android sdk installed on you computer?

Comment: It won't let me choose anything even though I've installed it?

Comment: why there is a small yellow triangle next to the package name?

Comment: Okay I think I need to review just what exactly it was I installed. Following the Android guide now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose a Build SDK. If there is nothing in that drop-down, please visit the SDK Manager (Window > Android SDK Manager) and download one or more SDK platforms and associated emulators.

Comment: I overlook this easy stuff all the time. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the SDK in Eclipse otherwise you will download them all and scratch your head on why they are not working.If you launch SDK manager form SDK folder and not from Eclipse it does not seem to register in Eclipse that you have downloaded these files. Took me several hours for something that should have taken only one or so.